# How can I call a method defined on a Scala package object from Java? (Scala 2.10.x)

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Given a method defined on a (3rd party, so I can't just move it) Scala package object, like so:

```
package foo

package object bar {
  def doSomething(s: String): String = ???
}
```

I need to call `doSomething` from Java code. I know that in general, I can get at a Scala companion object's methods from Java using `ScalaObject$.method()`. However, the example above compiles to `foo.bar.package$.class`, and of course Java screams about package being a reserved word.

Is there a way to call this from Java directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the package object as `foo.bar.package$.MODULE$` (note the dollar signs, do not remove them):

```
foo.bar.package$.MODULE$.doSomething("hello")
```

Answer (score 4):

The best I can come up with (works, but ugly) is to wrap `doSomething` in Scala code that's not in a package object, and then call the wrapper from my Java code.

```
object BarUtil {
  def wrapper(s: String) = foo.bar.doSomething(s)
}
```

and in Java

```
public String doIt(String s) {
    return BarUtil$.wrapper(s);
}
```